# ubuntu 20.04 digitalocean droplet nginx-rc cerbot and --nginx not installed

Tags: 20.04

I have a droplet from digital ocean which is running nginx-rc as the web server. when I try and run certbot --nginx to update the certificate, it comes up with an error saying component not installed - is there a way I can get the php3-certbot-nginx to work with nginx-rc.

Or is there a way I can run certbot to run against the nginx-rc instance...

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're using Ubuntu 20.04?  `nginx-rc` is *not* part of Ubuntu.

Comment: yes. the server was installed via runcloud, but I'm not using that anymore.